# Scoped NPM for private repository converts slash "/" to "%2F"

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus

I would like to fetch private npm from private repository using scopes.
I have set the .npmrc as such.

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@myco:registry=https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/
```

I have set the .yarnrc as such.

```
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
"@myco:registry" "https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/"
```

But when I do:

```
yarn --verbose add @myco/some-private-npm
```

It throws this error:

```
verbose 0.708 Performing "GET" request to "https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/@myco%2fsome-private-npm".
verbose 0.792 Request "https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/@myco%2fsome-private-npm" finished with status code 404.
```

When I do:

```
 yarn --verbose add @myco:some-private-npm
```

It goes to this 400 url (Nexus: Invalid repository path):

```
verbose 0.957 Request "https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/@myco:some-private-npm" finished with status code 400.
```

The actual npm is located at:

```
https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/myco/some-private-npm
```

How do I make sure the url fetched does not have "@" and "%2f" is a "/"?

Thanks!

Comment: Mentioning one more possibility - For me this was happening when i was using invalid/expired token, creating new one solved the issue for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this github issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3700) for yarn, try adding similar config to your .yarnrc:

```
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
"@myco:registry" "https://nexus.myco.com/nexus/repository/"
```

Failing that, I recommend perusing the linked issue and trying the solutions provided.

Comment: Thanks Klaycon, I had gone through the github issue as well and is very close to my issue. I do have the .yarnrc with quotes, still the issue remains.

[removed yarnrc config as comment does not format correctly]

Comment: @PH. Have you also tried installing with a : instead of /, i.e. `yarn --verbose add @myco:some-private-npm`?

Comment: I tried but it throws 400 error Invalid repository path. Updated the actual in the Q.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer as this is the closest solution. There are some with same issue who have this unresolved in the github issue.

Answer (score 1):

I run into exact the same issue some time ago.
check at NPM if your repository team access level is read/write.
On my side the team i was in had only read access level. Switching solved the issue.

Comment: I'd suggest add some examples, commands, some sources on the topic. Remember that your answer can be helpful to more than the person asked.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible scenario is that the slash encoding isn't really the problem. You simply do not have access to that specific repository.

That would explain the 404, since if you don't have access, for security reasons, it's as if it doesn't exist, you don't get a 401.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page when also trying to run `npm publish` of a .tgz file in Github Actions, and getting the following (replaced scope and package):

```sh
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@SCOPE%2fPACKAGE - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@SCOPE/PACKAGE@0.0.5' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

This package **IS** published so I thought the %2f was causing the issue.  I was using NPM_TOKEN as an environment variable as well, as per [npmjs documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow).

**Solution:**

```yaml
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
        with:
          node-version: '12'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
        
      - name: Publish to npmjs
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run pack
          npm publish <package tgz> --access public
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_APIKEY }}
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_APIKEY }}
```

via [Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/publishing-nodejs-packages#publishing-packages-to-the-npm-registry).

*NOTE:  I'm not sure NPM_TOKEN is still required here.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure .yarnrc actually contains
registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
and not
registry "registry.npmjs.org"
That'll give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I did not conform to [GitLab naming conventions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#naming-convention)

I had capital letters in my scope.